# Swift,php,mysql : how to get user information from database

Tags: php, mysql, swift

I am creating an simple app which takes user information and shows to the user who is sign in. it like sign in and sign up. I am successfull in inserting the sign up data to database but i don't know how to retrieve current user data when he wants to sign in using json format?

Comment: surely there is documentation you can read up on

Comment: from where i can get those documentation to fetch the json data in my iOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[When querying](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) you want to perform a SELECT on the table and then you can add in WHERE conditions and such.  Then a [mysqli_result object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object will be returned.  From there you can get the row with [fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)  this will return and associated array.

Now you're at the point where you need to convert the associated array to JSON, which can easily be done with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).